# SQL Query for Reporting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to join two tables and getting the data for my report. Is there any best way to get the details as per below report?

[image]

I have tried below query and getting the results. Please find my query.

```
SELECT  wl.trasaction_id
       ,wl.supplier_id
       ,wl.sp_patientpid
       ,wl.dm_id AS original_dm_id
       ,NVL(cr.new_dm_id,wl.dm_id) AS out_dm_id 
FROM weekly_load wl
LEFT JOIN cross_ref cr
ON wl.sp_patientpid = cr.sp_patient_id
AND wl.supplier_id = cr.ims_supplier_id
```

Kindly help me.

Many thanks.

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  It looks fine.

Comment: hi Gordon,thanks for reply. If i try with my real time data i am not getting expected results.

Comment: What results are you getting? Please edit post (not in comments). *Not getting expected results* could mean anything.

Comment: in what way are you not getting the expected results?

Comment: Removing NVL(), If you get all nulls, perhaps the value itself is null in actual data or the join goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need an additional `join` condition on the dm ids:

```
SELECT wl.trasaction_id, wl.supplier_id, wl.sp_patientpid, wl.dm_id AS original_dm_id,
       COALESCE(cr.new_dm_id, wl.dm_id) AS out_dm_id 
FROM weekly_load wl LEFT JOIN
     cross_ref cr
     ON wl.sp_patientpid = cr.sp_patient_id AND
        wl.supplier_id = cr.ims_supplier_id AND
        wl.dm_id = cr.old_dm_id;
```